# Are there research papers on related to algorithm fairness in theoretical computer science?

Tags: reference-request

I have seen several articles related to algorithmic fairness in machine learning and AI. I am not able to find out research paper on algorithm fairness in theoretical computer science. Kindly suggest some research articles also mention the future of algorithmic fairness in the theoretical computer science.

Comment: That's... a lot. There is an entire conference concerned with fairness (and some other topics, admittedly): [FAccT](https://facctconference.org/). You may want to check the proceedings; or check also for the word "fairness" or "calibration" in the proceedings of TCS conferences (STOC/FOCS), as well as the proceedings of FORC (Symposium on Foundations of Responsible Computing).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What about conferences which are below STOC/FOCS/SODA?

Comment: FORC and FAccT are conferences.

Comment: COCOON,CSR,FSTTCS etc.?

Comment: I... don't understand what you're asking for here. Many conferences will have, now and then, some papers on algorithmic fairness: check their proceedings with those keywords. But it might not be a large fraction of them, or that frequent: if you have a specific conference in mind, search its recent proceedings! The conferences I indicated specifically have this area in their call for papers (CfP), so you are more likely to easily find papers on algorithmic fairness there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to the curated sessions/talks on [Trustworthy ML](https://www.trustworthyml.org/)